# how to use firebaseui-web autoUpgradeAnonymousUsers?

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication

How to use [firebaseui-web autoUpgradeAnonymousUsers](https://github.com/firebase/firebaseui-web#upgrading-anonymous-users)?

Situation:
Before a user is signed-in / logged in, this page could be rendered. However, after a user is signed, I could no longer display this page using the same sample code as https://github.com/firebase/firebaseui-web.

[image]

I have set autoUpgradeAnonymousUser: true. So what are the steps to use autoUpgradeAnonymousUser. It is not available in the demo app source code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Before rendering FirebaseUI, you could call `firebase.auth().signInAnonymously()` to sign in on the Auth instance. And then pass the Auth instance to firebaseUI instance. If autoUpgrade config is turned on, when user click sign-in buttons, it would trigger the account linking to link google/facebook/password account to your anonymous account. However, you need to provide the SignInFailure callback in case there is merge conflict. Here you can find more detail and code sample: https://github.com/firebase/firebaseui-web#upgrading-anonymous-users

Comment: "And then pass the Auth instance to firebaseUI instance." How did you do this?

Comment: Is there a demo repo? @Ti Wang

Comment: Could you include how you perform anonymous upgrade in your demo repo of https://fir-ui-demo-84a6c.firebaseapp.com?

Comment: `var ui = new firebaseui.auth.AuthUI(firebase.auth());` 
Basically you as long as the auth instance has an anonymous user signing on it, the upgrade will be triggered. But you need to decide when you want the user to sign in anonymously yourself.